# Parsing hstore to remove sensitive information - PgSQL

Tags: sql, postgresql, pentaho, kettle, hstore

How do I remove sensitive user information from hstore column attributes, table dim_user. And load the rest into aggregate tables. I am selecting from PgSQL database and using Pentaho Data Integration to load data into aggregate tables.

```
attributes
""DURATION"=>"1", "END_DATE"=>"2017-07-18", "START_DATE"=>"2016-07-18", "AUTO_RENEWAL"=>"true", "MEMBER_SINCE"=>"Mon Jul 18 14:31:01 EDT 2016", "DURATION_TYPE"=>"YEARS", "SHIPPING_ADDRESS"=>"1 Glos Cres, Toronto, ON Canada A9l 111", "SUBSCRIPTION_TYPE"=>"MY_ADVANTAGE""
```

Need remove value of "SHIPPING_ADDRESS" from above.

RESULT

```
""DURATION"=>"1", "END_DATE"=>"2017-07-18", "START_DATE"=>"2016-07-18", "AUTO_RENEWAL"=>"true", "MEMBER_SINCE"=>"Mon Jul 18 14:31:01 EDT 2016", "DURATION_TYPE"=>"YEARS", "SUBSCRIPTION_TYPE"=>"MY_ADVANTAGE"
```

Thanks.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The hstore functions and operators are [described in the hstore documentation](https://www.postgresql.org/docs/current/static/hstore.html). It's relatively straightforward.

Instead of:

```
SELECT cola, colb, colc FROM dim_user;
```

You can do:

```
SELECT cola, colb, colc - 'SHIPPING_ADDRESS'::text FROM dim_user;
```

Answer (score 0):

Remove it while selecting:

```
select attributes - 'SIHPPING_ADDRESS' as attributes, 
       ... other columns ...
from dim_user;
```

Or create a view that does this, then select from the view in Kettle.